# How to read space seperated file which contains spaces in column also using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read one space separated file using python pandas. This file's first column contains some spaces so I'm not able to read this file successfully.

**Input File Data-**

```
       Jan1 Jan2 Jan3 Jan4 Jan5 total
A BC    1    2    4    4    5    16
PQ R    1    2    3    4    5    15
X Y Z    2    2    2    2    2    10
```

I'm tried to read it using below code -

```
df = pd.read_csv("text2.txt", sep = r"\s+",engine='python')
df.to_csv("out.csv",index=None)
```

I also tried to use -

> delim_whitespace=True

I want to generate csv file from this file which looks like below -

```
names,Jan1,Jan2,Jan3,Jan4,Jan5,total
A BC,1,2,4,4,5,16
PQ R,1,2,3,4,5,15
X Y Z,2,2,2,2,2,10
```

Is I'm missing some p

Comment: what about just df = pd.read_csv("text2.txt")?

Comment: Does the first column have a specific fixed width?  From your example it looks like it may not.  How would anyone know how to parse this?  Is the rule that the first column goes up to the first digit?  Or something else?

Comment: As @Noobie points out, this looks like a regular csv. The commas seem to correctly delimit both the names column and the numeric values. The result you have said you are looking for is achieved with `read_csv()`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse it semi-manually

```
def read_funny_csv(filehandle):
    columns = None
    index = list()
    data = list()

    split_pattern = re.compile('\s+')

    num_columns = None
    for line in filehandle:
        parts = split_pattern.split(line.strip())
        if num_columns is None:
            num_columns = len(parts)
            columns = parts
            continue
        index.append(' '.join(parts[:-num_columns]))
        data.append(parts[-num_columns:])
    return columns, index, data
```

## calling this

```
with open("text2.txt", 'r') as filehandle:
    columns, index, data = read_funny_csv(filehandle)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data, columns=columns)
```

You will have to specify the `dtypes` yourself.

If you want to make pandas make a stab at it itself you could export this to a decently delimited csv, and reload it